# Zlib decompression function copies instead of decompresses

Tags: c++, qt, zlib

I'm trying to implement archive handling in my application, using zlib on Linux. The app is written in C++ with Qt5.

This is my example function:

```
int Foo::decompress(const QString &file)
{
    char buffer[128];
    int num_read=0;
    gzFile fi = gzopen(file.toUtf8().constData(),"rb");
    FILE *outfile = fopen("/Data/test.unz", "wb");
    if (!fi || !outfile) return -1;
    while ((num_read = gzread(fi, buffer, sizeof(buffer))) > 0) {
    fwrite(buffer, 1, num_read, outfile);
    }
    gzclose(fi);
    fclose(outfile);
}
```

This code causes to copy whatever file I feed it , instead of decompressing it. I've read a few other zlib decompression topics, but all they do is add to my confusion.

Any help?

Comment: After running this, `/Data/test.unz` contains the unzipped content, right?  If not, are you sure that the input file was actually gzipped in the first place?  Does the `gunzip` command-line utility do what you want?

Comment: Well, no, as mentioned, it's just a copy of the zipped file. To be clear, I expect to use all sorts of archives in the future, but I'm using plain old zipped files for now.

Answer (score 0):

Then the input is not a gzip file. `gzread()` serves as a drop-in replacement for `fread()`, so that when the input is not a gzip file, it works like `fread()` and reads the file with no translation.

Since your input is apparently not a gzip file, and since you say "archive handling", it sounds like you are confused about the file formats. If you are trying to read a .zip file, that is an entirely different thing from a gzip file.